# How can I replace a numeric column with a character column of fixed width?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table that contains a zip code field (numeric type), and some of the zip codes contain only 4 digits. I need to pad the 4 digits zip codes with leading spaces.
I created a character filed as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table myTable as
select * , put(Zip,5.) as ZipChar
from Mytable;

create table myTable as
select *, case when Zip<10000 then " "||ZipChar else ZipChar end as Zip_Fixed
from Mytable;
quit;
```

Now my difficulty is how to locate Zip_Fixed instead of Zip column. Zip is a numeric type and Zip_Fixed is a character type. the replacement is necessary as the order of the column must be kept. I'm all ears for any other creative solution.

Thanks,
Adi

Comment: What do you mean by locate?

Comment: My table consists of about 200 columns, and "Zip" column is the 7th from the left. I need to have "Zip_Fixed" the 7th from the left, instead of "Zip" column.

Comment: Hm, one solution would be to list all columns in the order you want them, but with 200 columns this will be a lot of writing work e.G data mytable; retain var1 var2 .... var6 Zip_fixed var8 .....; set mytable; run; Not sure if an easier solution exists, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971999/the-most-efficient-way-to-reorder-columns-in-sas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a macro that reorders variables many months ago. It's probably not the shortest way of doing this, but it should solve your problem.

Assume you have a dataset and want to move `move_me` before `v1`

```
data temp;
   input v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 move_me;
   datalines;
    1 2 3 4 5 0
    1 2 3 4 5 0
    1 2 3 4 5 0
    ;
run;
```

Run the `%order` macro below:

```
%macro order(dsn, var1, before_or_after, var2);

/*  get list of variables in your dataset from dictionary.columns*/
    proc sql;
        create table vars as select 
            varnum, name
            from dictionary.columns
            where memname = upcase("&dsn.");
    quit;

/*  assign the final position of the variable that you want to move*/
    proc sql;
        create table vars2 as select
            a.*,
            case when a.name = "&var1." then max(b.varnum) else . end as varnum_want
            from vars as a
            left join vars (where = (name = "&var2.")) as b
            on a.varnum = b.varnum;
    quit;

/*  move the variable to that location*/
    data vars3 (drop = varnum_want);
        set vars2;

        %if &before_or_after. = before %then %do;
            if name = "&var1." then varnum = varnum_want - 0.5;
        %end;

            %else %if &before_or_after. = after %then %do;
                if name = "&var1." then varnum = varnum_want + 0.5;
            %end;

            %else %do;
                putlog "ERROR: Pick 'before' or 'after'";
            %end;

        proc sort; by varnum;

    run;

/*  select variables into a macro variable in correct order*/
    proc sql noprint;
        select name into: ordered_vars separated by " " from vars3 order by varnum;
    quit;

/*  reorder variables*/
    data &dsn._reordered;
        retain &ordered_vars.;
        set &dsn.;
    run;

%mend order;
```

And then you can use the syntax `%order(temp, move_me, before, v1);` to create a dataset called `temp_reordered` that has `move_me` slotted in before `v1`. In your case, it sounds like you would want to run `%order(myTable, zipFixed, before, [your 8th variable's name])` and then drop any extraneous variables to keep your variables ordered correctly.

Comment: Thank you, superfluous. Works like magic. I modified the macro just a bit so that it just adds "_R" to the reordered table, as I needed to invoke it few times. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, happy to help. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem (or wait for a potentially better one to appear).

Comment: Sure. And how do I accept your answer? I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: You should see a little check mark on the left near the up/down arrows.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of the `PUT()` function will create a character field with leading spaces.  Your second step will add another leading space.

Why not just use leading zeros instead?  Then the values will look more like numbers and still sort properly.

```
put(zip,Z5.)
```

If the final goal is to create a text file with fixed width fields (as one of your other comments mentions) then you just use the format in the PUT statement you use to write the text file.

```
data _null_;
  set mytable ;
  file 'myfile.txt'; 
  put ... zip 5. ... ;
run;
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. To your first point, here's how the columns I've added look like. It looks like I need the second step in order to have the zip code right justified.

 ZipChar  Zip_Fixed
28390 28390
45410 45410
 3816   3816

To your second point, even if I use leading zeros, I still need to replace a numeric column with a character one, as the order of the original columns must be kept.

Comment: thank you for you answer. You're right about your first point. To your second point, even if I use leading zeros, I still need to replace a numeric column with a character one, as the order of the original columns must be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Zip codes are typically padded with zeros as Tom notes, not with spaces.  They also can be three digits in a few cases (for example, Puerto Rico), so be aware of that.

Further, depending on your needs, formatting the column may be sufficient.  It won't change the contents of the numeric column, but it will change how it is displayed.

```
proc datasets;
  modify have;
  format zip z5.;
quit;
```

Again, for some use cases this won't be helpful, but for others it may be superior to converting to character.

Comment: Thank you, Joe. Unfortunately it's not my call whether to add zeros or not, as I need to submit a file to a state authority, in a Fixed Width format, and every numeric value has to be padded with spaces and not zeros, and to be right justified. The only way I had in mind was to convert it to a character type with leading spaces. I tried to use your piece of code but unfortunately I don't see any change in the type of "Zip" column. It is still numeric. Do I miss something here?

Comment: @benmeira The zip code *must* include the zero - the zero is a part of the zip code.  One zip code for Puerto Rico for example is `00901`  - `  901` is not a valid zip code.  In the use case you describe, it sounds like you could simply put the file out with the `z5.` format - or simply output in the field with spaces if you ignore the advice on zeros.  Most likely altering the dataset is the incorrect way to go about it.  I recommend asking a new question where you describe your output method - then we can give more specifically useful advice.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I believe that choosing the zip code as an a example was not the best idea. There are few numeric columns in my table that need to be padded with spaces. I chose to present only one as an example here, just to be concise, but apparently it took the focus out of my issue. Let us forget that we're talking about zip codes, and allow me to go back to my original question. How can I replace a numeric column with a character one? Thanks.

Comment: @benmeira If you're outputting to a fixed width file, you do it in the _output to the fixed width file_, not in the SAS dataset.  Ask a question showing how you are doing that, and we can help you with that.  Changing it in the SAS dataset is a waste of time.