# Reordering variables into a specific order in SAS

Tags: variables, sas, dataset

I'm looking to change my SAS dataset so the variables are ordered in a specific way. An example of the dataset:

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCKLX.png)

The variables are currently ordered as: ID, Level, FirstName, LastName, Email.
However I want the variables to be in the the order: FirstName, LastName, Email, ID, Level.

How would I do this in SAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the retain statement. A detailed note on the subject can be found here: http://support.sas.com/kb/8/395.html

Answer (score 2):

And the super lazy method of using SQL which returns the variables in the order specified.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select firstName, lastName, Email, ID, level
from have
order by firstName asc;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

SAS sets the order of variables in a new dataset by looking at the order it sees them inside of a data step.  If you have many variables, just reference the ones you want first... first.

```
data new;
   * set the length to match the data "set" you are reading from;
   length FirstName $12; 
   length LastName $35; 
   length email $20; 
   ID = .; * set the numeric to be missing; 
   Level = $2;
   set old; * SAS will fill in the actual variables here;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to present your data in a report with the variables in a specific order, do not bother reordering the underlying data. Simply do it in the PROC Print/Report/Tabulate.

If you must reorder the columns in the data, use a format/retain statement before the Set Statement. This will place the variables to your liking in the PDV.

Also, see the related thread [The most efficient way to reorder columns in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971999/the-most-efficient-way-to-reorder-columns-in-sas)